# Match all occurences outside of script tag

Tags: regex

I am looking for a way to match all occurences of the word `window` that are not inside `<script></script>` tags.

Is it possible to instruct this in a single `regex` ?

```
<div class="hidden">
    <div class="btn-group window-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default current"></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default prev"><i class="ed sf"></i></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default next"><i class="ed sf"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
<div component="tray" class="window-info">
    <div id="missing-window" class="window window-missing clearfix hide" component="msg">
        <button type="button" class="btn close" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
        <p>Window missing. Please try again.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="hide">
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            define(config.relative_path + '/assets/templates/bw_gj12.js', function () {
                console.log('path configured')
            });
        });
        window.addEventListener('unload', function () {
            leave_msg()
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

https://regex101.com/r/cOYTnH/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the regex flavour and how you want to use the results. One way would be to match the `<script>` area as a block and then match a `(window)` in alternation, then iterate over all matches and only use the captures. An example for the expression:

```
<script\b[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/script>|(window)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pW3MM0/1).

This works, because the regex engine will usually try to match the left side of an alternation first. Since that takes in the whole script block, it can't try to match `window` inside it. Thus, it will only ever try to match the second alternative outside of it.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Could I make a replace while keeping the script block then?

Comment: @Bhorys Depends on how you want to use it. In a programmming language you can usually iterate over all matches or use a match function to influence how the replacement is done. You need some logic that looks for the captured string in every match object and skips all those matches which don't have it, so using this regex directly in an editor would lead to replacing all matches, script block and window alike.